# How can I center content without content stretching?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, centering

I want to center the 2 images but the images are being stretched out of proportion because of display: flex but justify-content wont work without it

is there another solution to centering the images?

```
<div class="column-photo">
<div class="center">
<img src="img/2.%20GenerationAnxiety%20page%202,2.png" 
style="width:40vw;">

<img src="img/3.%20GenerationAnxiety%20page%203,3.png" 
style="width:40vw;">
</div>


column-photo {
flex-wrap: wrap;
flex: 33.33%;

}

.center {
display: flex;
justify-content: center!important;
align-content: center!important;
}
```

Comment: remove `style="width:40vw"` from your img tags. also you didn't close your `.column-photo` div tag

Comment: then I lose the ability to individually choose the size of each image

Comment: You should try adding `.column-photo img { flex-grow: 0; }`, that should prevent the stretching if they take up less than the full width of the flex container, while at smaller sizes they will still get adjusted properly.

Answer (score 0):

You have missed dot with class column-photo.

Alternate way without specific width

```
.column-photo {
 text-align:center;
  display:block;
}
.center {
  display:inline-block;
  float:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want stretch the images but keep the aspact ratio you should wrap the images in a div with a individual width. Then you can give the image a width of 100% to keep the aspact.

If you should use vw in this case is another question

```
<div class="column-photo">
  <div class="center">
    <div class="img-container" style="width: 40vw">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
    </div>
    <div class="img-container" style="width: 40vw">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

img{
  width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you've messed up some properties:

```css
.center {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="center">
  <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/843090368837042176/Nl-rCb9c_400x400.jpg" style="width:10vw;">

  <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/843090368837042176/Nl-rCb9c_400x400.jpg" style="width:20vw;">
</div>
```